# Fitness evaluation and training set in realtime simulation neuro-evolution

Tags: neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I am attempting to train a neural network to control a simple entity in a simulated 2D environment, currently by using a genetic algorithm.

Perhaps due to lack of familiarity with the correct terms, my searches have not yielded much information on how to treat fitness and training in cases where all the following conditions hold:

- There is no data available on correct outputs for given inputs.
- A performance evaluation can only be made after an extended period of interaction with the environment (with continuous controller input/output invocation).
- There is randomness inherent in the system.

Currently my approach is as follows:

- The NN inputs are instantaneous sensor readings of the entity and environment state.
- The outputs are instantaneous activation levels of its effectors, for example, a level of thrust for an actuator.
- I generate a performance value by running the simulation for a given NN controller, either for a preset period of simulation time, or until some system state is reached. The performance value is then assigned as appropriate based on observations of behaviour/final state.
- To prevent over-fitting, I repeat the above a number of times with different random generator seeds for the system, and assign a fitness using some metric such as average/lowest performance value.
- This is done for every individual at every generation. Within a given generation, for fairness each individual will use the same set of random seeds.

I have a couple of questions.

1. Is this a reasonable, standard approach to take for such a problem? Unsurprisingly it all adds up to a very computationally expensive process. I'm wondering if there are any methods to avoid having to rerun a simulation from scratch every time I produce a fitness value.
2. As stated, the same set of random seeds is used for the simulations for each individual in a generation. From one generation to the next, should this set remain static, or should it be different? My instinct was to use different seeds each generation to further avoid over-fitting, and that doing so would not have an adverse effect on the selective force. However, from my results, I'm unsure about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a reasonable approach, but genetic algorithms are not known for being very fast/efficient. Try hillclimbing and see if that is any faster. There are numerous other optimization methods, but nothing is great if you assume the function is a black box that you can only sample from. Reinforcement learning might work.

Using random seeds should prevent overfitting, but may not be necessary depending on how representative a static test is of average, and how easy it is to overfit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. There are indeed a great many methods out there, and not having a clear idea of whether and how they relate to each other is half the problem for me at the moment. I had read a bit on RL and thought that the idea of rewards given at every time step didn't seem to fit with my problem domain, but perhaps I didn't consider it enough.

Comment: Any chance you could elaborate a little on the black box comment? I suspect this is probably key but am not certain what you mean.

Comment: @kamrann In reinforcement learning, you treat it like a machine learning problem. You take the inputs, and then predict what the final fitness will be for every action you take. E.g. "moving left has a 10% higher chance of winning vs moving right."

The advantage is you can store the data, and then train for awhile offline, without having to do full simulations. You can also use gradient descent and fast learning methods.

I don't have much experience in it so I can't tell you how well it would work in practice.

Comment: @kamrann "Black box" is just a term that means treating the problem like a function you can only give a solution, and get back a number on how good it did. You can't see inside it, you are blind to how the parameters are affecting the fitness.

Comment: Right, it was the requirement to be able to predict rewards at the level of actions taken that I felt made RL unsuitable. In particular I'm looking to have agents learn a task which I don't myself know beforehand how best to solve. However, having read up some more I can see that RL is quite widely applicable and there is scope for me to give the agent some kind of ongoing hints/assessment of its actions within a simulation. I suspect the agent not having full knowledge of it's environment or of the effects of its actions will make this difficult, but I'll look into it. Thanks.